# Jenkins Add Credentials not showing any options

Tags: git, jenkins, credentials

I have Jenkins installed on the ubuntu server, the latest version is there and all plugins installed to the latest version as well.

When I tried to add credentials it shows to me the dropdown menu but without any boxes to fill the data.

I tried to check the security in manage Jenkins but it seems all is fine

I tried with HTTPS and git URL's but still the same.

Please check the screenshot to understand what I mean.

Thanks,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EegdP.png)

Answer (score 0):

The [Jenkins Git plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#using-credentials) is clear:

> The git plugin supports username / password credentials and private key credentials provided by the [Jenkins credentials plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials/).

So double-check said plugin is indeed installed/active.

Comment: as I mentioned in my questions, all plugins related downloaded to the latest version.
But still it's not working with me as shown in attachment screen shot

Comment: @HosamAl-Mowaqee Yes, I have seen the question, but the fact you see no option means the plugin is not properly installed/active, hence my answer.

Comment: so did you recommend uninstalling and install the plugin again?

Comment: @HosamAl-Mowaqee For example, to check why those options are not there even though the plugin should provide them.

Comment: I tried all the possibilities :(, the plugin of credential and everything else related to git plugins is updated to the latest version and still, it's not working.